# Página multilenguaje HTML PHP

Tags: php, html

Estoy trabajando en una web que tiene que ser multilenguaje (la estoy haciendo sin ningún framework) y me gustaría saber cuál es el mejor método para hacer esto.

He probado de hacerlo así:

```
if (!isset($_GET['lang']) && !isset($_SESSION['lang'])){
        $_SESSION['lang']="language/es.php";
        include ($_SESSION['lang']);
    } else {
        $_SESSION['lang']="language/".$_GET['lang'].".php";
        include ($_SESSION['lang']);
    }
```

Pero si recargo la página sin la variable `$_GET['lang'];` esa "sesión" no se me guarda ya que cada vez que recarga y no está la variable en la *url* vuelve a poner el idioma por defecto que es el español.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: si entiendes inglés mira: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953528/best-way-to-internationalize-simple-php-website. Lo que quieres se llama Internacionalizacion. buscando "internationalization php" en google puede salirte algo que te sirva

Comment: Ten en cuenta que la función `include()` añade una página: http://php.net/manual/es/function.include.php

Comment: No entiendo como funciona lo de internationalization, y sí con el include meto un archivo que tiene las strings con el texto tal que asiu 
$lang['index_string_1']="Esto es un ejemplo";
De esta manera cuando consiga solucionar mi problema de la sesion o solucionarlo de otra manera sin tener que utilizar sesion simplemente según el idioma escogido me va a mostrar las cadenas de texto que deseo.

Comment: Sólo para confirmar: ¿estás haciendo `session_start()` al principio del script?¿y estás incluyendo ese script en todas tus páginas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma de realizar una página multi-lenguaje es tener todos los strings separados en un archivo externo contenido en arrays.

Puedes dividir estos arrays con el `key`con el valor del lenguaje del navegador o el seleccionado, y en el `value` del array el string con el idioma pertinente.

Como te ha comentado @Ramon-san en su respuesta, lo suyo sería primeramente que cargara el lenguaje del navegador, y luego que pueda escoger el que desee el usuario.

Un ejemplo:

```
$lang = substr($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"],0,2);
$landingPageString = array(
    "es" => "Bienvenidos a nuestra página",
    "en" => "Welcome to hour site"
);
echo $landingPageString[$lang];
```

Este es un ejemplo muy básico y resumido. De este modo, te evitas crear dos o más veces la misma página con idiomas distintos, y lo tendrías todo en la misma página.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener el lenguaje del navegador del usuario que accede a la web mediante `$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]`:

```
$lang =substr($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"],0,2);
$_SESSION['lang']="language/".$lang.".php";
include ($_SESSION['lang']);
```

Comment: No acabo de comprender como funcion el $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]

Comment: Cuando un usuario accede a la web envía una petición HTTP GET al servidor para obtener la página. En la cabecera de esa petición incluye el idioma que tiene configurado en su navegador. Por ejemplo, si accedo a tu web con mi chrome en español, se enviará el código de idioma en HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE. Como te da el código entero incluida la variante, por ejemplo es-co para Colombia o en-us para inglés de Estados Unidos, utilizamos el substr para obtener sólo las dos letras que vamos a utilizar.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente se suele tener un fichero "base", por ejemplo, `textos.xml`, que contiene la versión original de las cadenas, que suele representar el inglés, y luego, por cada idioma, un fichero con las versiones traducidas: `textos_es.xml`, `textos_fr.xml`, etc.

Luego, la idea de tener un fichero base es para que sirva como idioma por defecto.

Una metodología posible sería:

- PHP lee el fichero `textos.xml` (traducciones originales), y la guarda en una estructura de tu conveniencia (un diccionario o lo que quieras).
- A través de `$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE]`, se lee el fichero de idioma correspondiente (`_es` por ejemplo), y se sobreescribir, en tu diccionario, las cadenas que aparezcan en el nuevo fichero.

De esta manera, `textos.xml` funcionará como fallback para aquellas cadenas no traducidas.

Si cambias de opinión sobre cuál debe ser el *fallback-language*, haz que `textos.xml` sea un `soft link` del idioma elegido, por ejemplo:

```
ln -s textos_en.xml textos.xml
```

De esta forma, puedes cambiar el idioma por defecto sin renombrar nada, solo cambiando a quién apunta el enlace.

Si en vez de un solo fichero quieres tener varios para organizar las cadenas un poquito, entonces puedes hacer uso de diferentes directorios en vez de diferentes nombres de fichero, por ejemplo.

Aunque lo que yo haría, sería tener todos los ficheros de todos los idiomas en una sola carpeta, por comodidad, y a través de algún fichero de configuración, indicar los diferentes ficheros base (por ejemplo, todos los enlaces).

Answer (score 0):

Para traer y mantener el lenguaje a lo largo de tu aplicación, usa una variable de sesión al inicio de cada archivo, por ejemplo `$_SESSION['lang']='it'` para tu archivo it.php. Dependiendo de la variable de sesión lang, puedes hacer lo que mejor se te acomode: llamar a otros archivos o funciones, como el menú en italiano, o llamar xml con los contenidos de acuerdo al lenguaje, lo que desees. Si el usuario no ha escogido nada, puedes dejar la variable vacía y el lenguaje por defecto.

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda iniciar sesión antes de hacer uso de la variable `$_SESSION`

```
// Iniciamos la sesión
session_start();

if (!isset($_GET['lang']) && !isset($_SESSION['lang'])){
    $_SESSION['lang']="language/es.php";
    include ($_SESSION['lang']);
} else {
    $_SESSION['lang']="language/".$_GET['lang'].".php";
    include ($_SESSION['lang']);
}
```

Y recuerda que tienes que usar `session_start()` en todos los scripts antes de usar la variable `$_SESSION`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el script ps-translate con un diccionario JSON personalizado, la variable del lenguaje predeterminado la puedes guardar en una cookie o usando por ejemplo la función: localStorage.setItem("lang", "en");

PS-Translate: https://github.com/Al3xand3rV/ps-translate

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).